# Create a pair based on conditions from two dataframes and multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have two dataframes:

a:

```
TransID    Currency       Amount
1                 CAD        100
2                 USD         90
```

b:

```
TransID    Currency       Amount
3                 CAD         80
4                 EUR        100
5                 CAD        110
```

The conditions are if two TransIDs have a common currency and the amount in table a is less than the amount in table b print the output as a pair of the two, i.e. in this case the output should be -

(1,3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't it be `(1,5)`, `(1,3)` has `Amount_a > Amount_b`?

```
(dfa.merge(dfb, on='Currency')
    .query('Amount_x < Amount_y')
    .filter(like='TransID')
    .values
)
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 5]], dtype=int64)
```